# Registering a Visual Studio 2008 Express product on an offline PC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio

I have a large project that was built with VS 2008 and don't want to upgrade the project to a 2010 version just yet. I have VS 2008 Express but the trial period expired and it's installed in a computer with no access to the internet.

To get the registration key I only know of clicking the link in VS 2008 to get to the registration page. But is there a place I can go where Microsoft can provide the key from just logging in from an online computer with my Live account so I can copy that to my offline computer?

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2015, the registration page returns a 404.

A workaround is to delete the following registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/VCExpress/9.0/Registration`